# Repeating JQuery $(document).ready();

Tags: jquery, reload

I have a page that reloads using the code below:

```
restart_btn.click(function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

However, I'd like re-run the `$(document).ready();` only, without reloading the page. Is this possible please?

Comment: Put whatever you have in .ready() in a function, recall that function? - Its hard to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: Since your document is ready earlier, you can't re-ready it.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all your current scripts that are currently in the document ready function inside a new function. Call that function on document ready and also on the click event.

Example below:

```
function ReadyFunctionScripts() {
    // All the scripts that are now in document ready goes here
    // ...

    // Clicking on button will run the scripts that were executed during document ready
    restart_btn.one('click', ReadyFunctionScripts);
}

// Call the function once on document ready
$(document).ready(ReadyFunctionScripts);
```